# How to forward request from one WCF to another WCF?

Tags: .net, wcf, endpointbehavior, iclientmessageinspector

I have a situation where I have to create a service A (kind of a Proxy service) which will in turn calls another service B (the real service). The client C will only know the service A. Service A will log the call and would just kind of forward the request to B. After it gets a reply from B, A logs the response and sends it back to the client C.
To achieve this scenario I have seen many examples but nothing seems to work. I do have a few limitations. I can't add the reference of the service B inside service A. I also can't create service references. Services A and B are totally different and they don't know each other.

```
    ---->      ---->
C           A           B        
    <----      <----
```

In A, inside BeforeSendRequest() of IClientMessageInspector, I had updated the request.Headers.To to the URI of the service B. But this method never gets called. I have also attached an EndPointBehavior to it.

My sample code below. I am using .Net 4.5.

SimpleMessageInspector class

```
public class SimpleMessageInspector: IClientMessageInspector
{
  public object BeforeSendRequest(request, channel) 
  {
     request.Headers.To = new Uri("http://localhost:8087/B");
  }
}
```

App.Config
...

```
<services>
   <service name="A" behaviorConfiguration="AServiceEndpointBehavior">
      <endpoint ... 
      <endpoint ...
      <host>
         <baseAddresses>
           <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8083/A">
         </baseAddresses> 
      </host>
    </service>
<services>
<behaviors>
   <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="AServiceEndpointBehavior">
         <simpleBehaviorExtension/>
      </behavior>
   </endpointBehaviors> 
   <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
         <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
         <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailsInFaults="False"/>
      </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors> 
</behaviors>
<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
   <add name="simpleBehaviorExtension" type="A.SimpleBehaviorExtensionElement, A" />
  </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>

...
```

In the end, the service A is never calling the service B. Where am I going wrong here?
Your help is appreciated.

By the way, there are few questions here in SO, but nothing seemed to work for my case.

Comment: Service B does not receive the message from client C, because the SOAP message generated by client C calling service A will not be received by B. The SOAP message is generated according to the service interface. If the interface of service A is connected to service B The interface is not the same, then the SOAP message of service A will not be received.

Comment: Why not just let client C call service B?

Comment: @DingPeng, first of all, thanks for your comment. The point is, C should not know about service B, that's why I said A as proxy service. Is there any way we can just forward the call from C via A without using routing service. Few blogs said that using this IClientMessageInspector method we can achieve that but it didn't even getting called. I am ready to put a bounty on this if anyone can help me. I have tried 4-5 different ways from net but nothing worked.

Comment: I think, I was misguided. There is no way A will call B just because of the "Headers.To" was changed. The more details I got about this work, the more it got cleared to me.